# C# Objectlistiew is not redrawing itself

Tags: c#, objectlistview

lately I have a problem with my objectlistview. I'm still not 100% sure why this happens but mostly when I try to clear my objectlistview with ClearObjects(); Method my OLV stops to working. I add/remove objects in it but I can't see the updated objectlist in OLV anymore and when I use the horizontal bar my columns look like [image: this]

It's like my OLV stop refresh itself. While OLV is in this situation however I still can add/remove objects and see the changes in label. It's just with the GUI is not refreshing after a point.

Comment: "lately" - what did you change?

Comment: I think I might had this issue before too but I was not testing so often. I have added a method that save all my listview into a file and then load it. This was the first time I experienced this issue. When I load my listview and then clear it for load it again this was the first time I saw this issue. So I was think this might be an issue about ClearObjects() method? I can't catch the issue always because its random. I load same listview when I re-open my application and it's working and on next restart suddenly it's not refreshing anymore after restarting again..

Comment: This is nearly impossible to answer without knowing your code. You should probably try narrow it down by yourself. The question as it stands is "unclear" and "too broad".

Comment: Is there any chance you are calling `BeginUpdate` and getting an swallowed Exception before `EndUpdate` (maybe one of your AspectGetters throws or something)?

Comment: I have a part which does BeginUpdate but I don't have any try catch blocks inside of it, but I will make sure I don't get any error between beginupdate and endupdate thanks :)

Comment: @ThomasN Thank you so much! I have test my listview. I have add a test button in my form and did 

 `Listview.BeginUpdate();
 Listview.ClearObjects();`

and when I add something to my listview I realize it was not refreshing correctly anymore. I'm still not sure where I get this error but I have covered my codes with Try-Finally blocks for now. I hope I won't get this error anymore. I will gladly accept your comment as answer if you move it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments:

Is there any chance you are calling `BeginUpdate` and getting a swallowed Exception before `EndUpdate`.

BeginUpdate suspends the drawing so if it isn't in a try finally it can result in this behaviour.